# Why is it that I sometimes find I am unable to edit a tag

Tags: bug, tag-wikis, suggested-edits

I'm chasing my research assistant badge, and editing tag wikis, but I find that on occasion that I get no edit button showing, for example with the tag for [error-000666](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000666) whether I click the *help us create it?* link, or if I come to it from the [list of tags](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags?page=18&tab=name) and use the *edit* link (I see both link to the same [location](https://gis.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/3617))

[image: no way to edit error 666]

Is this a GIS.SE bug, some odd thing to do with my browser, or the work of the devil?

Comment: @PolyGeo I the issue right now with http://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/pricing/info and http://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/scale-factor/info and http://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/composite/info and http://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/compatibility/info , I've just been editing some tags so could the issue be I've hit some edit limit?

Comment: I wonder if it is this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210416/215590

Comment: Thanks, I think that might be it, the [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/gis/query/503652/how-many-edits-and-editors-wouldve-been-blocked-if-we-rate-limited-pending-sug?LookbackDays=365&MaxPendingEdits=5) listed there if run for GIS shows I would have been affected by rate limiting. So question that follows is, could some warning be put on the info page, that there is a limit of 5 pending edits.

Answer (score 5):

I thought this was just because you do not yet have the [approve tag wiki edits](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) privilege that comes in at a reputation of 5,000.

I also wondered whether there might be a tag wiki edit pending.

When I look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/error-000666/info with moderator privileges I see:

[image]

so I could easily create the tag wiki by clicking `Create Tag Info` but I would like to investigate a little more first.

[Shouldn't there be an explanation for a missing Edit Tag Wiki button?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103760/shouldnt-there-be-an-explanation-for-a-missing-edit-tag-wiki-button) seems to shed a little more light on the history of tag wiki creation/editing functionality but I think fails to explain what you are seeing.

I've asked around in chat rooms and a few other moderators have taken a look but at the moment this seems to be non-reproducible so I don't think we'll be able to do much until it occurs again and remains reproducible.

---

As discussed in our comments I think we have now nailed the cause as being that you already have 5 suggested edits in the review queue and are being temporarily rate limited ([Rate limit suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits)).  This seems confusing so I have posted a feature request to Meta SE of  [Show banner rather than having Create Tag info button go missing when user has 5 pending suggested edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287447/show-banner-rather-than-having-create-tag-info-button-go-missing-when-user-has-5)

Comment: I get an edit button and I can edit some of the wikis, edits are subject to approval etc , but in this case there's no button, so I can't even suggest edits

Comment: I wonder if there is an approval pending on the ones you cannot suggest edits for. I'll need to get to a browser in the morning before I can try to investigate further.

Comment: No, there's no reputation requirement. Any logged-in user can propose a wiki for an existing tag, as it says right in the message in the screenshot. I have 101 rep and I see the “Create Tag info” button.

Comment: @nmtoken Can you confirm that you are still not able to see the “Create Tag info” button on that particular tag (just in case a pending edit by someone was discarded) and that you are logged in (just to be certain)?

Comment: It's obvious that I'm logged in, from the image - my rep for the badge is showing. @iant also confirms that he can't see the link in his answer

Comment: I'll check if I can now see the button when I get back to a PC. Don't seem to be able to check through the phone app.

Comment: I thought not being logged in was a long shot (and can now see that your image shows your badge progress) but I think @iant is talking about a link to a post not being found.

Comment: Logging back in on my PC I see I can that I can now propose edits again for the [tag:error-000666] tag and also for another tag I noticed this issue with ~ [tag:error-000464].  Neither tag has any content, so if it was a proposed change, the change was rejected, is that something you'd be able to see as a moderator; certainly there's no public history of edits for the tag.

Comment: I've asked around in chat rooms and a few other moderators have taken a look but at the moment this seems to be non-reproducible so I don't think we'll be able to do much until it occurs again and remains reproducible.

Answer (score -1):

I can't find a link but I think it is to do with how many upvotes you have on questions with that tag. So you may have not asked/answered many questions on `error-000666`.

Comment: No that can't be it, I mean I was able to [suggest edits for error-000111](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/219010/revisions) but I've never answered a question to do with that error: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000117?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Comment: No, there's no such requirement. Any logged-in user can propose a tag wiki for an existing tag, as it says right in the message in the screenshot.